# Placing an array into a file column column

Tags: java, arrays, file, multidimensional-array

I currently have a `.txt` file with one line that looks like:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I would like to place that one line into a 2d array so my file can come out like so:

```
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxx
```

Here's my `java` class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EncryptDecrypt {

    public static void encrypt() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("TextFile.txt"));
        String line = in.readLine();

        String[][] e = new String[5][3];

        // fill array
        for(int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < e.length; j++) {
                e[i][j] = line;
            }
        }

        // print array
        for(int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < e.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(e[i][j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        encrypt();
    }
}
```

When I run my java class, all I get is this which's not what I want:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Do you just want to reformat the file or do you want to parse the file into an internal structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either use a `2D array` of `char` or `1D array` of `String`

`'String' class` is already internally implemented as an `array of 'Char'`.

Just use a `1D array` of `String`, like:

```
String[] e = new String[3];
    // fill array
    for(int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            e[i] = line;
        }

    // print array
    for(int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(e[i]);

    }
```

The 2D version would be something like below (not recommended)

```
    String line = in.readLine();

 Char[][] e = new Char[3][5];

 for(int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < e.length; j++) {
                e[i][j] = line.charAt(j);//to access element at jth index of string
            }
        }

        // print array
        for(int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < e.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(e[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println()
        }
```

Anyways for printing you do not to store in array, just do:

```
int noOfRows = 3;
for(int i=0;i<noOfRows;i++){
 System.out.println(line)
}
```

Comment: Which one would be better in this case do you think?

Comment: @yabva89 1D is easier

Comment: Oh nice.  May you please show me the 2D version just out of curiosity?  I'm new to Java, I want to get in as much practice as I can.

Comment: I tried switching my `String` variables to `char` but it's not working because `readLine()` isn't supported with  `char`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate over the string like this:

```
String line = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

int colums = 7;

for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(line.charAt(i));
    if ((i + 1) % colums == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

A more declarative version is possible when using Guava's [Splitter](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#fixedLength(int)):

```
for (String token : Splitter.fixedLength(coluns).split(line)) {
    System.out.println(token);
}
```